# Hard Science Fiction/ Space Opera about vast wormhole like structure

Tags: story-identification, aliens, hard-sci-fi, wormhole

for the life of me, I can't remember the name or author of this book (or series). In it, there is this huge (infinite) wormhole like structure, that is home to a number of alien species, and can be exited at various points into strange universes etc, and through which the main characters (or some of them) are travelling. It is reminiscent of Baxter, Reynolds, Stephenson, Hamilton, Brin, etc...but if one of those authors, I cannot find the book/s (proabably a series). Any help much appreciated. Not that old, maybe 10 years ago or so (though I could be wrong)

Comment: Could it be [*Eon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29) by Greg Bear?

Comment: @user14111 I'd guess Eon too (setting roughly matches, plus it's Greg Bear who writes in a similar style to Baxter) but it might be too old (1985). If you're not planning to post it as a full answer let me know and I'll post one.

Comment: @tardigrade Please, do post your answer.

Comment: Are races (i.e. speed competitions) held in the wormhole structure?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it wasn't Eon or one of its sequels.

Comment: Yep yep yep, thank you it is definitely Eon, as soon as I read the words, 'the way' I realised it. Thank you! Sorry for the tardy reply, wasn't online over the weekend